# Generated HTML by javascript is not formatted correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to make a input field where I can search for friends in a list, these friends I retrieve from a xml file and I generate them using javascript

The code I generate this with:

```
friendListInDiv = document.createElement("p");
                    var link = document.createElement("a");
                    link.onclick = function() {
                        openChat(friendsXML[i].textContent)
                    };
                    var friendText = document
                            .createTextNode(friendsXML[i].textContent + ":"
                                    + statusXML[i].textContent);
                    link.appendChild(friendText);
                    friendListInDiv.appendChild(link);
                    friendDiv.appendChild(friendListInDiv);
```

Now the problem I'm facing I have demonstrated in a jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/x897pv9o/

As you can see if you type in "j" in the top input bar it hides all friends but type "j" in the bottom one it will still display "Joske"

This is because these tags

```
<div id="friendlist"><p><a>
Joske:
Offline</a></p><p><a>
Tom:
Offline</a></p><p><a>
Dirk:
Offline</a></p></div>
```

are not being formatted correctly, how can I make them format correctly?

Comment: You can use `trim()` to trim whitespaces before appending the textnode.

Comment: I slightly modified your source. Use

           <a><p>
          Joske:
         Offline</p></a>

instead of

          <p><a>

because I see it adds a blank line for your source list (inspect element in web browser). Maybe is about your style def.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shaunak D mentioned in a comment, you can use `.trim()` to remove preceding and trailing whitespace, including new lines, from text. You can either use this on your text content when creating the node, or use it in your search function to exclude new lines.

In `document.createTextNode`:

```
var friendText = document.createTextNode(
    friendsXML[i].textContent.trim() + ":" + statusXML[i].textContent);
```

In `$('#searchinfriend').keyup`:

```
$('#searchinfriend').keyup(function () {
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#friendlist p a').each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase();
        (text.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
    });
});
```